# Files not being shown in development

Tags: python

The users profile pictures are loading fine on https://rossdjangoawesomeapp2.herokuapp.com/ but when I use http://localhost:8000/ none of them are loading. I think the error probably started when I configured my site to work with AWS. And my difficulty now is I don't really know where to begin looking for advice on how to fix the issue.

**Settings.py**

```
import os
import django_heroku


BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))



SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')

DEBUG = (os.environ.get('DEBUG_VALUE')=='True')

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['rossdjangoawesomeapp.herokuapp.com']


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}




STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'blog-home'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD =  os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')
EMAIL_PORT = 587

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    #Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of 'allauth'
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

    #allauth specifc authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
    )

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')




AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add the local url 127.0.0.1:8000 / localhost:8000 into allowed host

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['rossdjangoawesomeapp.herokuapp.com', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1']
```